# setprecision(0) in windows(mvsc2010) rounds a value but in Linux(g++) it truncates. Is there a difference between their implementation in Platforms

Tags: linux, windows

```
double vd = 9.7122333333344;
stringstream sstream;
sstream.precision(0);
sstream<<std::fixed<<vd<<endl;
cout<<sstream.str()<<endl;
```

MSVC = 10, Linux = 9

Comment: Which g++ version are you using? I'm getting 10 on g++ on Linux. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5RCsIwDED/e4qAP9uHQ@dAXKt3qWkcga0tazsE8ey1MLdASHghL0HvjwNizge2OCZDil2IM@npIXYUNpIC2wGsnih4jQQhGinYRpg026r@COPScyRYDNzh1lzPbXtZo@ukKJayvrrg7yx0bRo/E3JgZ6tTvVOlyom@f/GbjFJLSbJmlAJdimr7qymlqrfRN@cf "C++ (gcc) – Try It Online")

Comment: I dont have the version now, but just now tried in windows with cygwin, gcc 6.4.0 it didnt round the value.